# Is it possible to rollback a tag or an attribute when generating an xml file?

Tags: android, xmlserializer

I'm trying to generate an xml file from an Android app.
Is it possible to catch and handle an exception while building the file ?
For example I don't want a single message preventing the creation of the xml file. I'm trying to catch the exception and to set the attribute which contains some invalid characters manually but it doesn't work.
Any idea ?

```
private String writeXml(List<Message> messages){
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("", "messages");
        serializer.attribute("", "number", String.valueOf(messages.size()));
        for (Message msg: messages){
            serializer.startTag("", "message");
            try {
                serializer.attribute("", "content", someContent);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                serializer.attribute("", "content", "invalidContent");
            }
            serializer.endTag("", "message");
        }
        serializer.endTag("", "messages");
        serializer.endDocument();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
}
```

Comment: what `doesn't work` ?

Comment: please read my message. My question is if 'someContent' contains some invalid characters that throw an exception how can I handle it and not corrupt the whole XML. I'm not looking to a way to escape the characters but to handle the exception properly

Comment: You said "it doesn't work" but we don't know what that means.  Nothing happens?  Incorrect output of XML?  Exception thrown?  Something else?  Help us to help you!

Comment: The resulting XML is broken because it contains the attribute 'content' with the 1st characters of 'someContent' (up until the unsupported characters) which means that the resulting xml is missing the closing quote

<message content="azer />